# how to make C# video source played in C++ window

Tags: c#, c++, video, window, handler

Our client use C++ code and they have a window, they give us this window's handle,

```
HWND playbackWndHandle
```

and let us play our video in this window. Our video source is from C# code, a class object inherit from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`. 
They let us make the window they give us the parent window and create a child window in it and show our video in the child window.

Here is the way I used but does not work really well, this is C# code, `m_UIVideoControl` is our video source and `parentHwnd` is the handler `playbackWndHandle` they give us.

This one has many bugs when playing the video, I wonder are there any other way to do that? Please let me know, thank you so much for everybody!

```
public void CreateHostHwnd(IntPtr parentHwnd)
        {
            // Set up the parameters for the host hwnd.
            parameters = new HwndSourceParameters("Video Window", 800,800);
            parameters.WindowStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD;
            parameters.SetPosition(0, 0);
            HwndSourceParameters parameters.ParentWindow = parentHwnd;

            // Create the host hwnd for the visuals.
            HwndSource myHwndSource = new HwndSource(parameters);
            myHwndSource.RootVisual = m_UIVideoControl;
        }
```

Comment: You are using the correct solution. Just debug and fix your issues!

Comment: Hi, this one can be used but it does not work really well when I try to resize the window, I cannot reset our video source as the RootVisual, I am trying to deal with that. I wonder are there any other way to do the same thing? I think there must be some other ways.